# Filename regex extraction

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'd like to get parts of the filename

filename`blabla_2009-001_name_surname-name_surname`

I'd like to get: 2009-001, name_surname, name_surname

I've come up with this, but it's no good

```
preg_match("/(?:[0-9-]{8})_(?:[a-z_]+)-(?:[a-z_]+)/", $filename, $matches);
```

Any pointers?

Thanks!
BR

Comment: You have answered your own question, but you're including the 'match but don't capture' modifier. Change your regex to `([0-9-]{8})_([a-z_]+)-([a-z_]+)` and you'll be home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming filename format doesn't change:

```
preg_match('#(\d{4}-\d{3})_(.*?)-(.*?)$#', $filename, $match);
```

Updated version to handle extension:

```
preg_match('#(\d{4}-\d{3})_(.*?)-(.*?)\.(.*?)$#', $filename, $match);
```

Comment: I forgot about the extension. I've tried playing with: ([a-z_]*?)$# but it won't work.

Comment: Update answer to account for extensions too

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("([0-9-]{8})_([^_]+)_([^_]+)-([^_]+)_([^_]+)$", $filename, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your file name is always that structure

```
$name = "blabla_2009-001_name_surname-name_surname";
$s = explode("_",$name,3);
$t = explode("-",end($s));
print "$s[1] $t[0] $t[1]\n";
```

output

```
$ php test.php
2009-001 name_surname name_surname
```

Comment: This gives `2009-001`, `name`, `surname-name`

Comment: The whole explode yes, but he's printing only the 2nd, 3rd and 4th elements of the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all,

I've updated my own solution As "nikc" pointed out...i just needed some direction...

here's the code if anyone will need a similar solution...

Thank you all!

```
preg_match('/([0-9-]{8})_([^-]+)-([a-z_]+).([a-z]+)/', $filename, $matches);
```